# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/bumptech/glide/Glide;

Tags: android, android-glide

simple `Glide.with(context).load(url).into(image)` not working after syncing the project with

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0-RC1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.0.0-RC1'
```

Comment: Can someone tell me why downvote? This is a valid problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> NoClassDefFoundError in Java comes when Java Virtual Machine is not
>   able to find a particular class at runtime which was available at
>   compile time.

If you use **compiler:4.0.0-RC1** Then add **`mavenCentral()`** in **`build.gradle`** Section .

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "//"
    minSdkVersion //
    targetSdkVersion //


    repositories {
     mavenCentral()
    }

}
```

Or Simply You can use **stable version** .

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
```

Comment: I have to add both: `mavenCentral()` and `glide` dependency.